Server component toggle stops working when trying to render a client element
//types/types.ts

export interface Component {
 id: string;
 category: Category;
 tag: Tag;
 name: string;
 desc: string;
 image: Image;
}


export interface Image {
 id: string;
 url: string;
}

export interface Category {
 slug: string;
 title: string;
}

export interface Tag {
 slug: string;
 title: string;
}

//Filter/filter.tsx

"use client";
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { cn } from "@/lib/utils";
import { Category, Tag } from "@/types/types";
import { useSearchParams, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import qs from "query-string";
import React from "react";

interface Props {
 data: (Category | Tag)[];
 name: string;
 valueKey: string;
}

const Filter = ({ data, name, valueKey }: Props) => {
 const searchParams = useSearchParams();
 const router = useRouter();

 const selectedValue = searchParams.get(valueKey);
 const onClick = (slug: string) => {
 const current = qs.parse(searchParams.toString());

 const query = {
   ...current,
   [valueKey]: slug,
 };

 if (current[valueKey] === slug) {
   query[valueKey] = null;
 }

 const url = qs.stringifyUrl(
   {
     url: window.location.href,
     query,
   }, 
   { skipNull: true }
 );
 router.push(url);
};
return (
 <div className="mb-8">
   <h3 className="text-lg font-semibold">{name}</h3>
   <hr className="my-4" />
   <div className="flex flex-wrap gap-2">
     {data.map((filter: any) => (
       <div key={filter.slug} className="flex items-center">
         <Button
           size="sm"
           className={cn(
             "rounded-md text-sm text-gray-800 bg-white border border-gray-300 shadow- 
 none",
             selectedValue === filter.slug && "bg-black text-white"
           )}
            onClick={() => onClick(filter.slug)}
          >
            {filter.title}
          </Button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
 );
};

export default Filter;

//Filter/filters.tsx

export const revalidate = 0;

import Filter from "@/components/elements/Filter/filter";
import { getComponentCategory, getTag } from "@/sanity/queries/page";
import React from "react";

type Props = {
 params?: {
 componentId: string;
};
 searchParams?: {
  category: string;
  tag: string;
 };
};

export const Filters = async ({ params, searchParams }: Props) => {
const categories = await getComponentCategory();
const tags = await getTag();
 return (
  <div className="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 pb-24">
    <div className="lg:grid lg:grid-cols-5 lg:gap-x-8">
      <div className="hidden lg:block">
        <Filter valueKey="category" name="Categories" data={categories} />
        <Filter valueKey="tag" name="Tags" data={tags} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 );
};

//mobile-menu/mobile-menu.tsx
"use client";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { ArrowLeftToLine, SlidersHorizontal } from "lucide-react";
import React, { useState } from "react";

type Props = {
 children: React.ReactNode;
};

const MobileNav = ({ children }: Props) => {
 const [showMenu, setShowMenu] = useState(false);
 const toggleMenu = () => {
  setShowMenu((prev) => !prev);
 };
 return (
  <div>
    <Button
      variant="outline"
      size="sm"
      className="font-medium text-slate-800/90"
      onClick={() => toggleMenu()}
    >
      <SlidersHorizontal className="w-4 h-4 mr-2 relative" />
      Filters
    </Button>
   <div>
     {showMenu ? (
       <div className="absolute z-10 bg-white w-[17.5rem] top-0 left-0 flex flex-col 
         py-2 border-r min-h-screen">
         <div className="border-b pb-2">
           <div className="flex items-center justify-between px-4">
             <h3 className="flex items-center">
               <SlidersHorizontal className="w-4 h-4 mr-2" />
               Filters
             </h3>
             <Button
               variant="ghost"
               size="sm"
               className=""
               onClick={() => toggleMenu()}
             >
               <ArrowLeftToLine className="w-4 h-4" />
             </Button>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div>{children}</div>
       </div>
      ) : null}
    </div>
  </div>
 );
};

export default MobileNav;

//filterbar/filterbar.tsx    

"use client";

import React, { useState } from "react";
import MobileNav from "@/components/layouts/mobile-menu/mobile-menu";
import { Filters } from "../Filter/filters";

type Props = {};

export const Filterbar = (props: Props) => {
 const [position, setPosition] = useState("bottom");
 return (
  <div className="relative flex items-center justify-between w-full px-4 md:px-10 py- 
    2">
   <MobileNav>
     <Filters />
   </MobileNav>
  </div>
 );
};

I am building a Nextjs app, and when I want to render the Filters component inside of MobileNav, the toggle of MobileNav does not work, hence the children cannot be seen. If for example I render something else inside the MobileNav, everything seems to be working just fine.
Your help will be welcome and appreciated. Thanks in advance.
